# How to convert array to string in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset of word in a array like:

```
arr: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([conversionevents], [elements], [pageviews], [productviews], [registrations], [sitepromotionclicks])
```

when I map this word I get:

```
val v = arr.map(x => println(x.toString))

[conversionevents]
[elements]
[pageviews]
[productviews]
[registrations]
[sitepromotionclicks]
```

and I would to convert this data to string to avoid the Square brackets []

Comment: The brackets should come from `Row.toString`. You could extract the first element of each row to get the string out of it. I'm not sure what you plan for rows with multiple entries.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x could you be more explicite?

Comment: I cannot test the code because I don't have spark installed, but you have an array of rows. If you print `arr(0)` the brackets will be included even for a single element. That means you need to look at the [documentation of Row](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html). On the top of that page is also an example how to use the Row interface with Scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the question the data is of `Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]` with only one element in each `Row`. so the simplest solution would be

```
scala> arr.map(x => x(0))
//res1: Array[Any] = Array(conversionevents, elements, pageviews, productviews)
```

> I would to convert this data to string to avoid the Square brackets []

```
scala> arr.map(x => x(0).toString)
//res2: Array[String] = Array(conversionevents, elements, pageviews, productviews)
```

But if you have data as

```
//arr: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([conversionevents,test1], [elements], [pageviews,test21,test22], [productviews])
```

above solution would reject rest of the values as

```
val result = arr.map(x => x(0))
//result: Array[Any] = Array(conversionevents, elements, pageviews, productviews)
```

the final solution is to use `flatMap` and `toSeq` as

```
val result = arr.flatMap(x => x.toSeq)
//result: Array[Any] = Array(conversionevents, test1, elements, pageviews, test21, test22, productviews)
```

and of course if you want them in `String` you can always use `toString` as

```
val result = arr.flatMap(x => x.toSeq.map(_.toString))
//result: Array[String] = Array(conversionevents, test1, elements, pageviews, test21, test22, productviews)
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: I'd skip the `.toString` during the map - it is better to have the exact class around, not only a string representation (e.g. `1 != "1"` but `1.toString == "1".toString` -- after the conversion you don't see the difference anymore  ). When the element is printed, toString is called automatically anyway.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x thanks for the comment. toString is because OP wants output in string.

Comment: what is the different if I use `getString(0)` instead of toString ?

Comment: @hisi yes you can use that definitely

Comment: `getString(0)` is the better choice - you should get an exception if the column is not a String. You should also check if the row is non-empty before you call getString(0) / row(0).